# CellForRowAtIndexPath is not invoked

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm writing an app hat has many views and I used sliding views library (`ECSlidingViews`). The problem is when I fill an array with objects and fill the table with the objects in `tableView:cellForRowIndexPath:` method, it does present the data in the table, but when I go to other view and come back the data disappears because `tableView:cellForRowIndexPath:` is not called.  Here is the code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   
{   
NSLog(@"begin of cellForRowAtIndexPath");    
SchedualeCell *cell = (SchedualeCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];    
Course *temp = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
cell.nameLb.text = temp.name;    
cell.hourLb.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",temp.hour];    
cell.startTimeLb.text = temp.startTime;    
cell.endTimeLb.text = temp.endTime;    
NSLog(@"End of cellForRowAtIndexPath");    
return cell;    
}
```

`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` is invoked when I come back to the view that has the table view.

P.S.: The view is `UIViewController` that has table view inside of it, and I searched all StackOverflow before posting my problem.

EDIT : this is where I set the delegate and datasource

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Did Appear");
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75f;
    self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
    self.view.layer.shadowColor= [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

    if (![self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController isKindOfClass:[MenuViewController class]])
    {
        self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];
    }
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];

    if (array == nil)
    {
        array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    table.delegate = self;
    table.dataSource = self;
    [table reloadData];

}
```

and I did included The delegate and datasource in the header

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate,addDelegate>
```

Comment: Did you try to reload the tableview when you come back?

Comment: Can you post more of your code?  When/where do you the set the delegate and datasource of your tableview?

Comment: Have you logged in numberOfRowsInSection ? If it's 0 then cellForRowAtIndexPath will never be called.

Comment: Did you set *both* the delegate and the data source??

Comment: yes I did set them both

Comment: @faisal60 : Have you solved your Problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all , it's not `numberOfRowsAtSection` and `numberOfTableView`. It's `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection`.

**Things you can do :**

**1)** `NSLog` your `numberOfRowsInSection`. Note that , If it's "0" then your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is never going to be called.

**2)** If you are using your `UITableView` inside some `UIView` then you should add :

```
[self.view addSubview:table];
```

**3)** Don't Forget to include :

```
@interface yourViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

Comment: I did write `NSLog` inside `numberOfRowsAtSection`and it returned "0" what can I do ? and I included the delegate and datasource in the header as you said but I didnt write `[self.view addSubview:table];` in my code cause I add the tableview in the view using the storyboard

Comment: @faisal60 : That means you have no Data to display in your Tableview, means Empty Array. Add some data to Array.

Comment: 1) NSLog your numberOfRowsInSection. Note that , If it's "0" then your cellForRowAtIndexPath is never going to be called. +1

Comment: I have never noticed this obvious thing that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` never gets called if  `numberOfRowsInSection` returns 0. Thanks for telling us that dude :D

Answer (score 0):

Once check that you reframed the `tableview` in `ViewWillAppear`.
Some times if we set out of frame, `CellForRowAtIndexPath` will not call.

Comment: So this should not have been down voted. This is absolutely true. Was going crazy trying to figure out why cellForRow wasn't being called - and it was because i forgot to set a bottom constraint and it was going offscreen!