# cellForRowAtIndexPath not called and numberOfSections and numberOfRows are bigger than zero

Tags: iphone, uitableview, delegates, simulator

I have a strange problem that ocurrs with simulator of iPhone 4 but not with simulator of iPhone 5...

The situation is: I have a screen composed by one VC that contains a TableViewController. In the class of VC I declared the delegates classes of UITableView (UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource). Also, I have pointed the delegate and the dataSource to File's Owner.

With this situation, I run the app at iPhone 5 Simulator and all works perfectly, but it I run the app at iPhone 4 Simulator, the TableView is not shown. This ocurrs with all test that I have done.

I hardcoded the return value of methods numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection for return always a number: "return 1" and "return 2", respectively. When I run it, step by step, I can see that values returned for these methods are ok, but when I force to call:

[tableview reloadData]

never call to cellForRowAtIndexPath...

Any idea??

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use the same xib for both iphone4 and iphone5? If so, perhaps your table just occupies some part of the screen at the bottom and you just don't see it in iphone4? :) (in this case cellForRowAtIndexPath won't be invoked)  And if you have two different xib files, then don't forget to point all the delegates in both of them

Comment: where you code is developed in 5 or 4?

Comment: Check My Answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16172169/1603072

Answer (score 0):

Check

- add `<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>` to .h declaration
- Connect the dataSource and delegate methods

Comment: All are ok. And If any of these checks were not ok, also don't work at iPhone 5 Simulator, and works great... the problem is at the iPhone 4 Simulator...